# XML cannot add odoo erp account in odoo10

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

The odoo erp system uses the XML append account to report an error. The user table does not have the user. The permission group cannot find the corresponding id. The field constraints are also assigned, and the solution is solved!
In order to solve this problem, I append the python default value, still show the constraints that the field can not be empty, and also tried to use sql to add users, still useless.

*My system is macos10.14,my python version is 2.7,my Postgresql version is 11,my odoo version is 10*

**res_admin_account.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="group_translation_user_login" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">Translation</field>
            <field name="login">trans_user</field>
            <field name="password">123456</field>
            <field name="lang">zh_CN</field>
            <field name="tz">Asia/Shanghai</field>
            <field name="active">True</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>


    </data>
</odoo>
```

**res_groups.xml**

```xml
<record id="module_account_payment_show" model="ir.module.category">
            <field name="name">收付款管理</field>
            <field name="sequence">33</field>
        </record>

        <record id="group_account_invoice_collections_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">发票收款</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="rh_account.module_account_payment_show"/>
            <field name="initial_group" eval="True"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4,ref('rh_base.group_translation_user_login'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="group_account_payment_inbound" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">收款</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="rh_account.module_account_payment_show"/>
            <field name="initial_group" eval="True"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4,ref('rh_base.group_translation_user_login'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="group_account_payment_outbound" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">付款</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="rh_account.module_account_payment_show"/>
            <field name="initial_group" eval="True"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4,ref('rh_base.group_translation_user_login'))]"/>
        </record>
```

**This is error infomation**

```xml
2019-09-24 11:12:28,569 16819 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0-20161220
2019-09-24 11:12:28,569 16819 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /Users/eric/odoo10/server/wuye-server.conf
2019-09-24 11:12:28,569 16819 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/eric/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/addons', u'/Users/eric/odoo10/enterprise', u'/Users/eric/Documents/rh_base/addons', u'/Users/eric/Documents/rh_gzw_property/addons', '/Users/eric/.virtualenv/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0.post20161220-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons']
2019-09-24 11:12:28,569 16819 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@localhost:5438
2019-09-24 11:12:28,576 16819 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8070
2019-09-24 11:12:30,030 16819 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2019-09-24 11:12:30,325 16819 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2019-09-24 11:12:30,862 16819 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2019-09-24 11:12:30,877 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2019-09-24 11:12:30,945 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.07s, 0 queries
2019-09-24 11:12:31,016 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading 72 modules...
2019-09-24 11:12:31,269 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.registry: module rh_base: creating or updating database tables
2019-09-24 11:12:31,533 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.addons.auth_crypt.models.res_users: Hashing passwords, may be slow for databases with many users...
2019-09-24 11:12:31,588 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/ir/ir_mail_server_view.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,631 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/ir/ir_sequence_view.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,736 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/ir/ir_translation_view.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,807 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/ir/ir_binary_attachment_view.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,837 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/data/ir_config_parameter_data.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,869 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/data/res_currency_data.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,875 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/data/res_company_data.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,880 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/data/res_base_report.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,908 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/data/res_groups.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:31,918 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/security/res_groups_access.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:32,047 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/security/res_groups.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:32,263 16819 INFO gzw-test odoo.modules.loading: loading rh_base/security/res_admin_account.xml
2019-09-24 11:12:32,266 16819 ERROR gzw-test odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 848, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 918, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 785, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 791, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1033, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 87, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1022, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: base.main_demo" while parsing /Users/eric/Documents/rh_base/addons/rh_base/security/res_admin_account.xml:4, near
<record id="group_translation_user_login" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">Translation</field>
            <field name="login">trans_user</field>
            <field name="password">123456</field>
            <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_demo"/>
            <field name="lang">zh_CN</field>
            <field name="tz">Asia/Shanghai</field>
            <field name="active">True</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>
2019-09-24 11:12:32,453 16819 INFO gzw-test werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2019 11:12:32] "GET /web?debug=%2F HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2019-09-24 11:12:32,460 16819 ERROR gzw-test werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/.virtualenv/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/eric/.virtualenv/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/service/server.py", line 246, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 1280, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/Users/eric/.virtualenv/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 227, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 1454, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/Users/eric/.virtualenv/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0.post20161220-py2.7.egg/odoo/__init__.py", line 55, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 55, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 848, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 918, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 785, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 791, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1033, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 87, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eric/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1022, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: base.main_demo" while parsing /Users/eric/Documents/rh_base/addons/rh_base/security/res_admin_account.xml:4, near
<record id="group_translation_user_login" model="res.users">
            <field name="name">Translation</field>
            <field name="login">trans_user</field>
            <field name="password">123456</field>
            <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_demo"/>
            <field name="lang">zh_CN</field>
            <field name="tz">Asia/Shanghai</field>
            <field name="active">True</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>
^C2019-09-24 11:13:54,520 16819 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating shutdown
2019-09-24 11:13:54,520 16819 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
```

**manifest.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
    'name': 'RuiHe base patch',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'depends': ['base','mail','report'],
    'author': 'DavidLee',
    'website': 'www.rhcpa.com',
    'description': """
       RuiHe Base
    """,
    'data': [
        'ir/ir_mail_server_view.xml',
        'ir/ir_sequence_view.xml',
        'ir/ir_translation_view.xml',
        'ir/ir_binary_attachment_view.xml',

        'data/ir_config_parameter_data.xml',
        'data/res_currency_data.xml',
        'data/res_company_data.xml',
        'data/res_base_report.xml',
        'data/res_groups.xml',
        'security/res_groups_access.xml',
        'security/res_groups.xml',
        'security/res_admin_account.xml',

        'res/res_groups_view.xml',
        'res/res_users_view.xml',
        'res/res_company_view.xml',
        # 'data/res_users_data.xml',
        'data/ir_translation_update.xml',
    ],
    'qweb': [
    ],
    'demo':[

    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
    'auto_install': True,
    'sequence': 3,
    'maintainer': 'Developer',
}
```

Comment: How do you load the XML files in your Manifest file? In key `demo` or in key `data`? Because `base.main_demo` is only there if the database was initialized with demo data.

Comment: @CZoellner I put res_admin_account.xml in **security/res_admin_account.xml** under data in **_openerp_. Is** the location loaded incorrectly?Now,I added my current Manifest file to my problem description.

Comment: The problem is using `base.main_demo` which isn't in the database when it's not loaded with demo data. You probably should use `base.main_company` instead.

Comment: @CZoellner Thank you! I have solved the problem, mainly adding partner and loading depends on XML, including sale, account and other model dependencies.